# Why do I get Error#2036 in flash AS3 and how to solve this?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, rss

I'm currently building an application in flash in relation to RSS/XML feeds for a project. I'm stuck at the moment because I keep getting this error:

> Error opening URL 'http://distilleryimage6.instagram.com/.jpg'
>   Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2036: Load Never Completed.

I know my string picURL is not functioning properly, but am I missing something that makes it not functional? This is my code:

```
package  {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;


public class instagramFeed extends MovieClip {
    //link to #rit xml loader
    public var ritFileRequest = new URLRequest("http://instagram.com/tags/rit/feed/recent.rss");
    public var ritXmlLoader = new URLLoader();

    //link to #rochester xml loader
    // same as above public variables

    public function instagramFeed() {
        // constructor code
        trace("About to load...");

        //Loads #rit hashtag xml data.
        ritXmlLoader.load(ritFileRequest);
        ritXmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, displayRITInfo);
    }

    //focuses on data with #rit hashtag
    public function displayRITInfo(e:Event):void{
        var ritInstagramData:XML = new XML(ritXmlLoader.data);
        var ritInfoList:XMLList = ritInstagramData.elements().item;
        trace(ritInfoList);

        //load the image
        var ritPic:String = ritInfoList.*::condition.@code;
        var picURL:String = "http://distilleryimage6.instagram.com/" + ritPic + ".jpg";
        trace(picURL);

        //show the image on the stage!
        var ritImageRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(picURL);
        var ritImageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        ritImageLoader.load(ritImageRequest);

        addChild(ritImageLoader);

        ritImageLoader.x=200;
        ritImageLoader.y=100;
        ritImageLoader.scaleX = 3;
        ritImageLoader.scaleY = 3;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: There is no "code" property on the link nodes. not sure what your `condition.@code` is trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue lies in your XML parsing of that RSS feed.

I'd recommend brushing up on e4x. This is a good resource for doing just that: http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/?page=4

I think your issue lies in this line: `ritInfoList.*::condition.@code`

Try modifying this line like so

```
var ritInfoList:XMLList = ritInstagramData..item;  //this will get all the item nodes
```

Then this line like so:

```
var ritPic:String = ritInfoList[2]; //this grabs the value from the 3rd link node as a test
```

That value is a fully qualified URL i noticed, so you don't need the line following `var picURL:String = "http://distilleryimage6.instagram.com/" + ritPic + ".jpg";` because `ritPic` is already the full URL.

Comment: I did what you suggested, I see that the first edit does get the full URL. I also deleted the ritPic variable, thanks for that part, I completely overlooked that. However, it still throws an error?? 

The error is:

Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found. 

I'm going to look into the tutorial soon (in an hour), really appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

An IO Error occurs (at least in this instance) when you send a request to a URL that does not exist. If you you throw `http://distilleryimage6.instagram.com/.jpg` into your browser, you will get an error page. This is your issue. Direct your loader to a proper URL and you will not get the IO Error

It also proper to handle IO Errors within your code.

```
var ritImageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
ritImageLoader.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, this.ioErrorHandler );
ritImageLoader.load(ritImageRequest);

private function ioErrorHandler( e:IOErrorEvent = null ):void {
    trace('An IO Error has occurred. You can use this function to display an error to the user or load a placeholder or whatever you wish');
}
```

This will prevent the app from crashing due to that specific error. The error is still there, keep that in mind. You do need to handle that error. Your app just won't die on you if it is dispatched anymore.

Comment: It does work. Your problems are multi-fold. This is how you handle the error you posted. It will not fix your URLs, but you should *always* handle your IO Errors. That is for every single URL you load. If you don't, you run the risk of this error occurring and crashing your application